# Providing input data for web scraping

Tags: java, web-scraping

I want to scrap data from the following site:
http://www.upmandiparishad.in/commodityWiseAll.aspx

There are two input elements, `Commodity` and `Date`. How do I provide these values and retrieve the resulting information?

Comment: dont  down vote any one

Comment: The people are downvoting because your question was poorly formed and it shows no research effort. I have rephrased it for you. In the future, put some real effort in your questions and the research. Also check my answer below for some useful tips.

Answer (score 0):

To extract data from a web page from Java, you can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

To provide input elements, you need to understand how they are provided originally by your browser.
Basically, there are two most common methods for a request-response between a client and a server:

- GET - Requests data from a specified resource
- POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

You can find more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

When you select the `Commodity` and the `Date` input values, you can investigate the methods used to provide those values to the server by examining network requests. For example, in Chrome, you can press F12 and select the `Network` tab to check the information being sent to and from the browser.

When you find out the way of providing the data, you can then form your HTTP request accordingly to provide the same data via `jsoup` or similar library.
For example, here is how you can provide simple input fields to your request:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/")
.data("some_input_1", "some_data_1")
.data("some_input_2", "some_data_2")
.post();
```

This is ofcourse just to get you started, it is by no means a complete answer. You need to show real effort on your side to search for answers online, as there are plenty.

Here are just a few to get you started:

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/
- http://simplescrape.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077532/learn-java/java-tip-34--posting-via-java.html